# How to make a code reusable in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

In my WordPress' projects, I'm using the following code again and again for many of my fields where I'm using a button to initiate the WordPress media uploader and on selection of the file I'm sending its path/url to a text field.

```
var project_field_image_uploader;

$('#button-input').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //if the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
        if( project_field_image_uploader ) {
            project_field_image_uploader.open();
            return;
        }

        //extend the wp.media object
        project_field_image_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media( {
            title:"Choose an image",
            button:{
                text: "Insert"
            },
            multiple: false
        } );

        //when a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
        project_field_image_uploader.on( 'select', function() {
            attachment = project_field_image_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            $('#text-field').val(attachment.url);
        });

    //Open the uploader dialog
    project_field_image_uploader.open();

});
```

For each of the field I need to edit the following things:

1. First variable - `project_field_image_uploader` (not necessarily it should be meaningful, it is only for creating different instances, so in a reusable way, it can be anything, but not conflicting)
2. Button's ID - `$('#button-input')`
3. Text field's ID - `$('#text-field')`
4. Media Library Modal's head - `title:"Choose an image",`
5. Media Library's Media Insertion button's text - `text: "Insert"`

Is there a way I can make this code reusable, so that I can be with `DRY` ideology? A jQuery function may do the job for me, but I cannot sort things out, how can I sort this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @alamnaryab for his answer that directed me to the right way (+1 for that). But passing a variable as a function parameter was problematic. It produces an error:

> `project_field_image_uploader` is not defined

I figured out things that, a variable need not to pass as a function parameter to be unique, because a variable inside a function is a local variable. So I simply called the variable inside the function and reused the function multiple times. I'm here posting the working example code.

And declaring multiple variables, I used comma with a single `var` declaration. There's no need to repeat things. Thanks again to Mr. Alam Naryab.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#button-input').click(function(e){
        var text_field = $('#text-field'),
            media_lib_head = 'Choose an image',
            btn_text = 'Insert';

        //using the function where necessary
        project_reusable_repeating_func( e, text_field, media_lib_head, btn_text );
    });
});

/**
 * Reusable function
 * @author alamnaryab
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/32035149/1743124
 */
function project_reusable_repeating_func( e, text_field, media_lib_head, btn_text ){

    //a variable that need not to be unique, because it's local
    var project_field_image_uploader;

    e.preventDefault();

    //if the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
    if( project_field_image_uploader ) {
        project_field_image_uploader.open();
        return;
    }

    //extend the wp.media object
    project_field_image_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media( {
        title: media_lib_head,
        button:{
            text: btn_text
        },
        multiple: false
    } );

    //when a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
    project_field_image_uploader.on( 'select', function() {
        attachment = project_field_image_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        text_field.val(attachment.url);
    });

    //Open the uploader dialog
    project_field_image_uploader.open();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#button-input').click(function(e){
        var text_field = $('#text-field');
        ....................
        var mytext = 'my text';

        myfunc(e,project_field_image_uploader,text_field,mytitle,mytext);
    });
   //reuse with any other button click with different parameters

});
function myfunc(e,project_field_image_uploader,text_field,mytitle,mytext){

   e.preventDefault();

    //if the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
    if( project_field_image_uploader ) {
        project_field_image_uploader.open();
        return;
    }

    //extend the wp.media object
    project_field_image_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media( {
        title:mytitle,
        button:{
            text: mytext
        },
        multiple: false
    } );

    //when a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
    project_field_image_uploader.on( 'select', function() {
        attachment = project_field_image_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        text_field.val(attachment.url);
    });

//Open the uploader dialog
project_field_image_uploader.open();
}
</script>
```

Comment: The challenge is: how to pass a variable as a variable. Your code, on click produces error: `project_field_image_uploader` is not defined.

Comment: same as you text_field & mytext are sent